# How do I make my own interactive FlyoutContent?

Tags: c#, maui

I am currently trying to design my own FlyoutContent (it's in Shell and it displays controls to switch displayed page) since properties exposed in Style are quite limiting ( or I don't know how to use them).

I have looked into ms docs and there I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout#replace-flyout-content) - way to design your own FlyoutContent.

In it is Label and well ... it behaves like Label. And that's the problem.

So it's a bug that it's not interactive and I can't click on it to change displayed page or do I have to add my own "sauce" to make it work ? If the later how would I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: If you want interactive, then use a Button or some other control that responds to interaction, or add a GestureRecognizer to the Label, or use the Selected options of the CollectionView

Comment: @Jason : Yes but you still need some code which will be triggered and which will change current displayed page by button's command/clicked or by collectionview's selectionchanged

Comment: Yes, you would have to write that code.  Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Jason for pointing me in the right direction!

```
<Shell
    x:Name="shell"
    ...
    >
   
    <Shell.FlyoutContent>

        <CollectionView BindingContext="{x:Reference shell}"
                        IsGrouped="True"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding FlyoutItems}" 
                        SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="FlyoutItem">

                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>

    </Shell.FlyoutContent>

    <FlyoutItem Title="MainPage">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate MainPage}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>

    ...

</Shell>
```

And then method in related .xaml.cs

```
async private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) =>
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{e.CurrentSelection[0].GetType().GetProperty("Route").GetValue(e.CurrentSelection[0])}");
```

Probably not the best way it could have been done but it works.